# Facing issues in creating blob in Azure

Tags: php, azure, cloud, blob, azure-blob-storage

How to create a blob in a container in Microsoft Azure using PHP.
Followed the steps in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs)

But still facing some issues. The PHP code is not getting executed.
How to push a file or directory into existing blob?

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServiceException;

$connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https://sen123.blob.core.windows.net/srs123/sen123;AccountName=sen@gmail.com;AccountKey= ";

// Create blob REST proxy.
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);

$content = fopen("D:\home\site\wwwroot\blobfile.txt", "r");
$blob_name = "sen123";

try    {
//Upload blob
$blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("mycontainer", $blob_name, $content);
}
catch(ServiceException $e){
// Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
// Error codes and messages are here:
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179439.aspx
$code = $e->getCode();
$error_message = $e->getMessage();
echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}

?>
```

Error message: This page isn’t working
sen.azurewebsites.net is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Are you getting any error message? do share the screenshot of the error message.

Comment: Please share the code and the details of any error message. Please do not share the screenshot. Instead copy and paste the error message as text.

Comment: @VikranthS changes have been made to the question.

Comment: @GauravMantri changes have been made to the question.

Comment: One issue that I definitely see is that your storage account name is incorrect. Based on the information you provided, the correct account name should be `sen123`. Can you change that and try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your connection string is incorrect.

   - The value of **DefaultEndpointsProtocol** should be `https` or `http`, not the URL of your blob file.
   - For **AccountName** and **AccountKey** you can copy these values from the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com):

   [image]
2. On the Windows platform, you need to change the file path to:

   ```
   $content = fopen("D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\blobfile.txt", "r");
   ```

   - See http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php